# Toggle size img on click

Tags: jquery

I have an **image list** which is 250 px height with class product.

If I click on the image it must become 500 px.
if I click the image again it must become 250px back.
if I click again it must become 500 px.

so basically I want to toggle between the height of the image.

What I have.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
       
       $('.product').click(function()
       {
    
          $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
          $(this).animate({height: "500px"}, 'fast');
       });
     
     $('.product').dblclick(function()
       {
    
          $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
          $(this).animate({height: "250px"}, 'fast');
       });

   });
</script>
```

this makes the image bigger on single click and smaller on doubleclick.

but I want to do the doubleclick action when the image is 500px.

**all images which are 500px must become 250 again if I click on another picture, so there will only be 1 picture 500px;**

What is the best way to achieve this? an if else statement, or is it possible to toggle height?

Comment: You could try and put the dblclick listener in the ready of the click animate. So it can only be fired after the click animate is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, set the `cursor: pointer` style in your CSS!

Then use a flag for the toggle effect :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var flag = true;
   $('.product').click(function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({height: (flag ? "500px" : "250px") }, 'fast');
       flag = !flag;
   });
 });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aNf2F/1/)

**EDIT:**

For multiple images using `data()` would probably be a better approach, and I'll include how to make the other images with the same class small as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.product').click(function () {
        $('.product').not(this).animate({height: "250px"}, 'fast');
        var $this = $(this),
            flag = !$this.data('flag');

        $this.stop().animate({height: (flag ? "500px" : "250px")}, 'fast')
             .data('flag', flag);
      });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aNf2F/16/)

Comment: Bah, global variables. This approach only works if there's exactly one such image on the page. Toggle `$(this).data('flag')` instead for better containment. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/aNf2F/5/

Comment: @Blazemonger - It's not really global, it's within the scope of the DOM ready function ;). I do agree with using data(), but it's a lot easier to explain this approach to newbies.

Comment: But he did specify that he had an "image list", not a single image.

Comment: And i want to make all the others  small so only 1 can be big.

Comment: @Blazemonger - added a little more !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aNf2F/8/  will make all the others go small but i have to click the image 2 times first click everything becomes small again, second click the selected img is big

Comment: @SvenB: It's not good manners to change the parameters of your question after answers have already been submitted. Just sayin'. Anyway, you can probably figure that part out just by using [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) or [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not) -- http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/aNf2F/15/

Comment: Blazemonger if i try your last fiddle with 2 imgs (both class="product")  ther must only be 1 big. so if i have  2 images and picture 1 is big and 2 is small and i click 2 2 must become big and 1 small

Comment: Updated the answer, added @Blazemonger 's maiximum optimizations with caching selectors etc. and functionality for more images.

Comment: Thx for the help ! the last update from Blazemonger is hte solution

Comment: Can you explain what you do at .data('flag',false);
            $this.data('flag', flag);

Answer (score 0):

Assign a variable of 1 for click and 0 for unclick and then use the .click function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
TriggerClick = 0;

$(".product").click(function(){
 if(TriggerClick==0){
     TriggerClick=1;
     $("div#test").animate({width:'100px'}, 500);
 }else{
     TriggerClick=0;
     $("div#test").animate({width:'300px'}, 500);
 };
 });
});
```